# Is there a more Pythonic way of changing `None` to `[]` than

Tags: syntax, coding-style, python

Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this?:

```
            if self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] is None:
                self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] = []
            if self.name2info[name]['optionals'] is None:
                self.name2info[name]['optionals'] = []
```

The reason I do this is because I need to iterate over those later. They're `None` to begin with sometimes because that's the default value. It's my workaround to not making `[]` a default value.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not change the default value to [] in the first place (I am assuming you are using a `defaultdict`)?

Comment: No, I'm not. I've used them before but not much. It would probably be useful in this case though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer this:

`self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] = self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] or []`

Comment: Both `None` and `[]` evaluate to `False`, don't they? Why does that work?

Comment: @Alex:  yes, [] will evaluate to False, so if the entry is already an empty list then it will be replaced by another empty list.  The only time this will be an issue is if you want multiple entries to refer to the same list - most of the time you do NOT want this, and having multiple references to the same list can cause subtle bugs (e.g. when using an empty list as a default parameter to a function, which is a common beginner's mistake).

Comment: If you drop the explicit test `is None` you basically replace everything that **evaluates** to `False` in a boolean context with an empty list: `None`, but also `''` (empty string), `[]` (empty list), `{}` (empty dictiontary), `0` (zero), `False` (boolean). This might at one point be a factor for introducing harder to catch errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't fix the input you **could** do this (becomes 'better' if you need to add more):

```
for prop in ['prereqs', 'optionals']:
    if self.name2info[name][prop] is None:
        self.name2info[name][prop] = []
```

But replacing these values to be **iterating** over the *empty list* you just added doesn't make a whole lot of sense (unless maybe if you're appending something to this list at some point). So maybe you could just move the test for `None`-ness right before the iteration:

```
prereqs = self.name2info[name]['prereqs']
if prereqs is not None:
    for prereq in prereqs:
        do_stuff(prereq)
```

Slightly going off-topic now, but if you ever want to test if an item is iterable at all, a common (pythonic) way would be  to write:

```
try:
    my_iterable_obj = iter(my_obj)
except TypeError:
    # not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
if not self.name2info[name]['prereqs']: self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] = []
```

or this way

```
self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] = [] if not self.name2info[name]['prereqs'] else self.name2info[name]['prereqs']
```

Comment: What if `self.name2info[name]['prereqs']` contains `False` instead of `None`? I think you should test explicitly for None with `if x is None`...

Comment: I suppose it depends on what he wants - it looks like (from his code) that the `prereqs` will either be None, or a list of values. Even a single-element list `[False]` equates to True. Of course **if the OP is planning to store any values besides a list or None, then you are correct**. But if `prereqs` will always be contained in a list, then my method is perfectly appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Every one of those attribute and dict lookups takes time and processing.  It's Pythonic to look up self.name2info[name] just once, and then work with a temporary name bound to that dict:

```
rec = self.name2info[name]
for key in "prereqs optionals required elective distance".split():
    if key not in rec or rec[key] is None:
        rec[key] = []
```

Now if need to add another category, like "AP_credit", you just add that to the string of key names.

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating over them I assume they're stored in a list. In which case combining some of the above approaches would probably be best.

```
seq=list(map(lambda x: x or [], seq))
```

Is a concise way of doing it. To my knowledge conversions in map() are faster than explicit for loops because the loops are run in the underlying C code.